# npm is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm

When I try to run `npm install` on windows, I get the following error. How can get rid of it?

```
D:\Xampp\htdocs\laravelchat>npm install
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Update the environment variables and then try to run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see `C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe` has two slashes `\`. You need to remove `\` from the end of `C:\Program Files\nodejs\` which is defined in environment variable. Follow following steps to set up path for nodejs and npm

1. Open the system properties (enter `sysdm.cpl` in command prompt), and click **`Advanced`** tab.
2. Click **`Environmental Variables`**. A pop-up window will open displaying **`Path`** under **`System Variables`**. Check whether the **`Path`** is determined as **`C:\Program Files\nodejs`** or **`C:\Program Files (*86)\nodejs`**. Remember not to include **`\`** at the end. If **`Path`** is not determined, append the path manually by clicking Edit.

Comment: this error also showing while checking npm -v, please help

Comment: node -v is showing correctly, but npm is not, i have installed and also uninstall, reinstalled it

Comment: See the image that I linked in comment and tell whether you selected it or not during installation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159167/discussion-between-prashant-pokhriyal-and-nayeem-riddhi).

Comment: i have watched this image

Answer (score 2):

You must install NodeJs if you didn't install it yet.
[NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/)