# npm failed to correctly download with node

Tags: node.js

Trying to install node, when checking if npm is installed from the command prompt, i get this:

```
C:\Users\apete>npm -v

'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
6.13.4
```

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling, restarting. When I open npm-cli.js it has an invalid character error.

I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330736/npm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-windows) post to the point where they [join a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159167/discussion-between-prashant-pokhriyal-and-nayeem-riddhi) and they never reveal how they solve the issue. I have tried everything else they suggested in the post. They said the user had not installed npm correctly. Is there any fail-safe way to install npm?

Comment: When checking _how_? What part of what you're showing is what you typed, and what part is console output?

Comment: clarified what the code part is

Comment: Thanks. But next time, please search first. This seems the same question as [npm is not recognized as an internal or external command in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330736/npm-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-in-windows), which I found by searching for the error you're showing. And if it isn't, it's important to say why this question is different.

Comment: I have followed that post to the point where they [join a chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159167/discussion-between-prashant-pokhriyal-and-nayeem-riddhi) and they never reveal how they solve the issue. I have tried everything else they suggested in the post. They said the user had not installed npm correctly. Is there any fail-safe way to install npm?

Comment: That's valuable information, so please update your post to mention that (because your post is where all the details go, not the comment thread).